# Java , Oracle query every seconds hits CPU

Tags: java, sql, oracle

i have oracle database.
i have a very basic java program that query a table every seconds to check the status of each records and update it.

```
"SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE STATUS =10 AND MODUS<10"
```

im using OJB for this program.
the java program runs 10 threads.

This program cause high CPU utilizations , in average 40% from the total Sun CPU. I have created index for that specific query. 
Yes, every seconds , that table will have data and the program have to process it.

I want to know, what is the better way in JAVA or Oracle to minimize the CPU utilization and also to achieve this kind of program running every seconds. 
My target is to process 200 records every 1 minute.
Thanks

Comment: looks like you have a mixed bag in your table: arriving records and processed records. If that's the case, your query will take increasingly amount of time as the table grows.  I'd separate the data intake process from the storage.

Comment: It depends on many factors. How are you processing the returned rows? Are you actually using every column (i.e., do you really need `select *...`)? Is 40% actually okay, or is it having a negative impact? Can you processing the data in some other way, like via message queues and store data during that process? Etc.

Comment: How are you measuring CPU? top? How many records does the table contain? How many are typically returned? Do you have an index on both status and modus? Are they the right types of index for the query? Have you checked the query plan to make sure it uses the indexes?

Comment: hi all,thanks for the response. basically i will have 200 records at most every minute. Yes index on both field. Query plan did state the use of indexes. What i saw, when i decreased the thread from 10 to 5 , the CPU starts to shrink. That 40% led to 100% CPU from existing.

Comment: Are you adding 200 records per minute or are you selecting up to 200 existing records per minute?  Can you have a trigger which adds new entries to another table allowing you to only poll the latest entries?

Comment: selecting and updating every seconds. when i checked oracle session, that table doesnt stop doing transaction and it is busy. Petey, do you mean , QUERY another table after INSERT and update back the main table ?

Comment: Also are you creating a new connection every second? Creating connections is expensive, make sure your connection pooling is working correctly. Do all threads select the same data or do they select different rows? If they select the same rows, you might have some locking issue where several threads wait and update the same rows. If this is the main activity on the DB, you might want to run an AWR report and look at the wait events to see what exactly the database is doing.

Comment: Hi Vincent, im using OJB persistent connection, i believed it is handled well by OJB.Every thread will select different records, and every update will update different records. It seems that 1 table have lot of transactions.

Comment: "every seconds to check the status of each records and update it." - then you're probably trying to fix the wrong problem. Why don't you handle the proposed update synchronously with the query that caused the record to be in this state in the first place?

Comment: Without knowing the full requirements it's difficult to advise.  My guess here is that you don't need to "poll" the table at all, just implement a post_update(insert/delete) trigger(s) to do the status chchecking and data changing you want.

Comment: Do you really need 10 threads to process 200 records per minute? I suspect that's more threads than are really needed. Try cutting down to one thread and see how that works.  In my experience once the number of threads exceeds the number of CPU's the value of the additional threads is minimal, and may actually hurt more than help.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a convoluted design. I'd recommend to look into AQ.